# Join then subquery on two Mongo collections

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have two collections in my MongoDB, 'Masters' and 'Details'.

The document / **objects** within the 'Masters' **collection** are structured like so:

```
|------------------|
| _id              |
| SharedCode       |
| Name             |
| Child[]          |
|------------------|
```

The 'Masters' document has a nested array of 'Child' documents.

A 'Child' document / **object** is structured as follows:

```
|------------------|
| _id              |
| SharedCode       |
| Name             |
|------------------|
```

The documents / **objects** within the 'Details' **collection** are structured like so:

```
|------------------|
| _id              |
| SharedCode       |
| Description      |
|------------------|
```

What I want to do, is build an array of composite models where:

- The masters documents are left joined on the details collection.
- The nested child documents are left joined on the details collection.

The projected result should be an IEnumerable (or concrete implementation of IEnumerable) where 'CompositeObject' has the following structure:

```
|------------------|
| SharedCode       |
| Name             |
| Description      |
| CompositeChild[] |
|------------------|
```

And its CompositeChild document is structured as follows:

```
|------------------|
| SharedCode       |
| Description      |
| Name             |
|------------------|
```

I have successfully joined the 'Masters' and 'Details' documents, but I am struggling to add a subquery to join the 'Child" and 'Details' documents.

The _id property is the ID assigned by mongo.

ShortCode, Description and Name are all strings.

Child is an object / type in itself as is CompositeChild.

(Models and use case simplified for brevity)

Answer (score 0):

What about following :

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataBase db = new DataBase();

            var results = (from m in db.masters
                           join c in db.children on m._id equals c._id
                           join d in db.details on m._id equals d._id
                           select new { master = m, child = c, details = d })
                           .GroupBy(x => x.master._id)
                           .Select(x => new
                           {
                               name = x.First().master.Name,
                               description = x.First().details.Description,
                               children = x.Select(y => new { childName = y.child.Name, sharedCode = y.child.SharedCode }).ToArray()
                           }).ToArray();
        }

    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public List<Master> masters { get; set; }
        public List<Child> children { get; set; }
        public List<Details> details { get; set; }
    }
    public class Master
    {
        public int _id { get; set;}
        public string SharedCode  { set; get;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Child { get; set; }  
    }
    public class Child
    {
        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string SharedCode { set; get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Details
    {
        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string SharedCode { set; get; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: A couple of things - the 'Child' property on the 'Master' class should be of type List<Child> or similar enumerable collection. Also, I am querying MongoDB, not a c# object (e.g. the DataBase class you have defined). Also, there are just two collections in the mongoDB - Master and Details.

Comment: Data bases usually do not have Lists.  You have to join tables.  Are you sure your database model actually have lists?

Comment: The c# mongodb library provides a strongly typed abstraction over the Json documents stored in the database and these are mapped to C# classes.